# PHP vs Java: Base64 en-/decoding of special characters

Tags: java, php, base64

I've got an encrypted string in PHP and need to send this in an HTTP request. So I decide to use Base64 encoding and URL encoding. The received is a Java module; but when I use the Base64 decoder, it shows me a completely different string. How can I get the original encrypted string back. I need actually to pick each character from that original string and use its corresponding ASCII code for decryption.

```
// PHP code
```

$encrypted = "©’Ÿ£ šd¤¨m";
$base64 = base64_encode($string);
$parameter = urlencode($base64);

// this returns eventually: qZKfo6CaZKSobQ%3D%3D

```
// Java code
```

// FYI: the variable "name" is a string that the Java software extracts from the posted data. 
String base64 = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
byte[] bytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
String encrypted = new String(bytes);

// This returns: ������d��m

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: edited my code to explain where "name" comes from, it's the Java software API that extracts it from the posted data. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Basically I can't generate your `qZKfo6CaZKSobQ==` in Java from the `"©’Ÿ£ šd¤¨m"`.

Comment: I should have asked: "What character set is your PHP file saved with?"

Comment: I guess your first data was on Windows, or in a Windows browser. The bytes in your base64 match those chars in the Windows-1252 characterset but not most others. In Java the constructor `String (bytes[])` uses  a default charset that varies depending on platform and sometimes environment settings, and it looks like yours used ASCII. You should get your chars if you specify charset "windows-1252". But in Java you needn't and shouldn't convert to String if you want to decrypt; Java crypto uses byte[] for data precisely because bytes are the same on all systems but chars aren't.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Even though PHP is on a LAMP, you were absolutely right about the char set; I found out that new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1") worked! I don't use Java crypto, but I have a custom encryption where I need the ASCII code of every character in the string.